# effect of colClasses in read.csv function

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I want the function to only give a character value as output, but when read.csv takes default value for colClasses there is additional output with the character value. Why is it that my function works well when I specify colClasses = "character" but not otherwise?

```
    top <- function(state, outcome) {
      a <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")
      if (outcome == "heart attack") {
            data <- a[a[[7]]==state,]
            x <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(data[[11]]))
            y <- min(x, na.rm = TRUE)
            index <- which(x == y)
            z <- data[index,2]
            z1 <- sort(z)
         print(z1[1]) 
      }
}
```

the output (with unwanted info about levels) is

```
> top("TX", "heart attack")
[1] CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER
4510 Levels: ABBEVILLE AREA MEDICAL CENTER ... ZUNI COMPREHENSIVE COMMUNITY HEALTH CENTER
```

Comment: The assignment directions for programming assignment 3 in the Johns Hopkins *R Programming* course on Coursera clearly state to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when reading the data with `read.csv()`.  Also, you're violating the Coursera Honor Code by posting a complete version of the `best()` function on the internet.

Comment: I've posted a tiny fraction of the whole code and it doesn't even run the way it should. Nevertheless, I understand your concerns and I have changed the name of the function so that plagiarism doesn't take place. The only way someone will realize this is from _R Programming_  is by reading your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factors (the data type R uses to store categorical variables) carry their possible levels along with them, and these are printed by default. There are a variety of solutions:

- use `colClasses` when reading in the data as you suggested;
- use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`
- read the file as usual, then use `print(as.character(z1[1]))`
- use `print(z1[1],max.levels=0)`